# Unable to access global methods in Firebase Functions project

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I expect multiple functions in my Firebase admin project to have the same methods For ex: "generate a random alphanumeric string". So to avoid the boiler plate code, I have created a Utils folder and a utilityFunctions.ts file inside that folder. The file just contains one export function that generates a alphanumeric string. I have imported that file into one of my functions file with an import statement.

Here is my File that contains the intended global method: src/Utils/utilityFunctions.ts

```
export const theRandomDocId = function randomDocumentId(length: number): 
String {
// the code to generate a random string
}
```

Here is one of my Function File: src/Compliment/addNewCompliment.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
//This import statement below for the utilityFunctions file
import utilityFunctions = require('../Utils/utilityFunctions')

export const addTheNewCompliment = functions.region('asia-east2').https.onCall((complimentData, 
context) => {

//generate random 11 alphanumeric ComplimentId converted to String
const randomComplimentId = utilityFunctions.theRandomDocId(28)

//There is a lot more code in this file but since its not relevant to the 
//problem, I have excluded it.

}
```

Here is the error that is shown by vs code:

```
!  functions[addNewCompliment(asia-east2)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../Utils/utilityFunctions'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/Compliment/addNewCompliment.js:5:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

I have also tried declaring the method without the export variable and accessing the method from my addNewCompliment.ts file without an import statement, the code compiles but when it is triggered the Firebase Functions log throws an error:

```
Unhandled error ReferenceError: randomDocumentId is not defined
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "functions",
"scripts": {
"lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
"build": "tsc",
"serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
"shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
"node": "8"
},
"main": "lib/index.js",
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/storage": "^4.7.0",
"@types/sharp": "^0.25.0",
"child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
"firebase-admin": "^8.9.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.6.2",
"fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
"sharp": "^0.25.2"
},
   "devDependencies": {
"tslint": "^5.12.0",
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
},
"private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to [include the local modules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#including_local_nodejs_modules_as_part_of_your_deployment_package) as part of your deployment package? It would be helpful if you could update the question with more information about your file structure, as well as the package.json file.

Comment: Hi pessolato, I have update the question with my package.json file, I have not included the local modules as part of the deployment package... When add it to the package.json file I get this error: Error: Cannot find module '../Utils/utilityFunctions'

Comment: Hi pessolato, after a lot of reading and trial & error. I figured out how including the local modules works.... Thanks for the comment, it pointed me in the right direction.....

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Utils` directory inside your `functions` directory? When deploying, only the `functions` directory is sent to the server, so anything that is not in that directory won't be uploaded. If that's not the issue, make sure your capitalization matches as the Cloud Functions backend has a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes it is in the functions directory. regarding capitalization I dont understand exactly what I may be doing wrong there, all the code is mentioned above... Is there something I am missing there.. could you please expand on that....